# Apply Different Functions to Different Groups and Multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to python and trying to apply different functions to different groups and multiple columns in pandas. I have been reading, but can seem to find a solution.

For simplicity below is what I want to do.

```
import pandas as pd

dat = {
    'group': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2'],
    'age': [40, 29, 34, 35, 37, 32, 36],
    'weight': [150, 175, 135, 125, 189, 178, 137],
    'score': [98.0, 77.0, 88.0, 78.0, 78.0, 85.0, 84.0]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
```

1. For the age column, I want to create the mean age by group using the following code `(df.groupby('group').transform('mean'))`
2. for the weight and score columns I want to create grand mean centered data by group means using the following code `(df.groupby('group').transform('mean').sub(df.mean()))`

I am having some problems putting these together in a function that would run over the dataset.

@TYZ

What I was looking for is a function like below:

```
def gmc(data):

  d = []
        
  # set the index of the dataframe to group
  s = data.set_index('group')
            
  # groupby and transform on level=0 to calculate the group mean
  d.append(s.groupby(level=0).transform('mean').sub(s.mean(numeric_only=True)).reset_index())
        
  # groupby and transform on level=0 to calculate the group mean and reset the index
  d.append(data.groupby(data.iloc[:, 0]).age.transform('mean'))

  return d
```

Where it gives me the grouped mean values for column age, and the group grand mean centered values for weight and score, like below:

```
    group   age    weight     score
 0     1    33.75  3.928571    3.0
 1     1    33.75  3.928571    3.0
 2     1    33.75  3.928571    3.0
 3     2    36.00 -5.238095   -4.0
 4     2    36.00 -5.238095   -4.0
 5     1    33.75  3.928571    3.0
 6     2    36.00 -5.238095   -4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.groupby("group").agg({
    "age": np.mean,
    "weight": lambda x: np.mean(x) - df["weight"].mean(),
    "score": lambda x: np.mean(x) - df["score"].mean()})

# output
         age    weight  score
group                        
1      33.75  3.928571    3.0
2      36.00 -5.238095   -4.0
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure what other columns you have and what other functions you are applying. What I noticed is, all your 3 columns are applying the mean function, then for `weight` and `score`, you have an additional step to subtract the overall mean. So I will do:

```
res = df.groupby("group").agg(np.mean)
for c in ["weight", "score"]:
    res[c] = res[c] - df[c].mean()
```

Comment: I have more than three columns in the data, so I was looking for a way not to do each column individually.

Comment: @GSA If you are looking for more, please provide more detail in your question, otherwise we will only be able to solve the exact problem you posted.

Comment: what I wanted was a more general way to say to apply the codes  to more than two columns without listing each column individually.

Comment: @GSA How would the code know which column to apply what function if you don't list them and map them??